# R scatterplot3d turn x axis text 45°

Tags: r, text, 3d, axis, scatter-plot

I have something like this, and want to turn xlabels 45 degrees (it is going to be rather long text):

```
a<-c(1:10)
b<-c(1:10)
c<-c(1:10)
  scatterplot3d(a,b,c,
                main="3-D Scatterplot",color="blue", pch=19,
                type="h", lty.hplot=2, box=F,
            scale.y=.5, 
            lty.grid=1,
            lab=c(9,5,1),
            xlab="",
            ylab="",
            zlab="")
```

Comment: Your trials so far? We don't do the work for you, pleas improve the question with your attempts, results from your researches which didn't bring the solution, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
library(scatterplot3d)
a<-c(1:10)
b<-c(1:10)
c<-c(1:10)
#remove x labels using x.ticklabs = ''
scatterplot3d(a,b,c,
              main="3-D Scatterplot",color="blue", pch=19,
              type="h", lty.hplot=2, box=F,
              scale.y=.5, 
              lty.grid=1,
              lab=c(9,5,1),
              xlab="",
              ylab="",
              zlab="", x.ticklabs='')
#add the labels using the text function. srt specifies the angle.
text(x=b, y=1, pos=1, labels=b, srt=45, adj=1, xpd=TRUE, offset=0.5)
```

And it works!

[image]

Comment: Works great. Maybe useful for others: as I used data from poLCA it had to be specified that b<-c(1:10) is a vector with the number of categories and not the input data. Thank you very much!

Comment: Great! Glad I could be of help :)